# apply mask on np.array in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a `pd.DataFrame` containing a mask and `np.array`. I want to apply the mask on the array (like I would do with `np.where`)

Does anyone have an idea how to succeed ?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Mask'   : [[True, False, True], [False, False], [True, True]],
                   'Array'  : [[2, 5,4]           , [1, 0]        , [4, 5],],
                   'Result' : [[2, 4]             , []            , [4,5]]})

def ffilter(entry):
    return entry['Array']['Mask']

df.apply(ffilter) #--> Nope too easy :-(
```

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: Calculate means, std, minimum and maximums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just create a mask by using `df.Mask`, pass it to the `mask()` function of the data frame and aggregate.

This would be the "*one-liner*":

```
pd.DataFrame(df.Array.tolist())\
    .mask(np.asarray(df.Mask.tolist()))\
    .agg(['mean', 'std', 'min', 'max'])
```

which gives you:

```
        0         1
mean  1.0  2.500000
std   NaN  3.535534
min   1.0  0.000000
max   1.0  5.000000
```

---

Or as a whole:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Mask'   : [[True, False], [False, False], [True, True]],
                   'Array'  : [[2, 5]       , [1, 0]        , [4, 5],],
                   'Result' : [[2]          , []            , [4, 5]]})

df_Array = pd.DataFrame(df.Array.tolist())
mask = np.asarray(df.Mask.tolist())

df_Array.mask(mask).agg(['mean', 'std', 'min', 'max'])
```

---

From the comments, it is still not clear what your desired output is. I'll just assume you want to calculate statistics like min, max, std etc for each of these array in your data frame - and further - have a data frame where each row represents one of those arrays:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Mask'   : [[True, False, True], [False, False], [True, True]],
                   'Array'  : [[2, 5,4]           , [1, 0]        , [4, 5],],
                   'Result' : [[2, 4]             , []            , [4,5]]})

df_stats = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.Array)[x.Mask]
                    .agg(['min', 'max', 'std', 'mean']), 1)

print(df_stats)
```

which produces:

```
   min  max       std  mean
0  2.0  4.0  1.414214   3.0
1  NaN  NaN       NaN   NaN
2  4.0  5.0  0.707107   4.5
```

Comment: The problem I didn't mention is that the arrays have different size. Also I wanted the `agg` feature  in the other axis. I will update the post

Comment: @LaurentR It is not clear what your expected output is. Please give an exact example of your expected output.

Comment: my problem is applying a mask on an array, both contained in a `pd.DataFrame`. The question has been updated with different size arrays the result I'm looking for is the Result column. The agg features is not my problem, only the final step that could be improved (currently I'm using `df['result']apply(lambda x: x.mean())`.

Comment: @LaurentR By example I meant an actual example of the final data frame which you are expecting. I now assume that you just want to calculate some basic statistics for all of these arrays and retrieve a data frame which contains these stats.

Answer (score 0):

That does the trick even if it's not really pythonic.

```
arr = df.Array.tolist()
mask = df.Mask.tolist()

result = [[np.asarray(a)[m]] for a, m in zip(arr, (mask))]
result

>>>[[array([2, 4])], [array([], dtype=int64)], [array([4, 5])]]
```